# Remove empty < >

Tags: php, php-7

Is there a way to remove `< >` if it's empty?

the text can be;
`<  > Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, < > when an <b>unknown printer</b> took <> a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries. <     >`

output should be;
`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an <b>unknown printer</b> took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$text = "<  > Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, < > when an <b>unknown printer</b> took <> a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries. <     >";
$text = preg_replace('/<\s*\>/', '', $text);
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,  when an <b>unknown printer</b> took  a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4MG5S)

If you also want to clean up any multiple or hanging spaces (at beginning or end of line) from the removal of the empty `<>`, you can use this instead:

```
$text = preg_replace(array('/<\s*\>/', '/\s+/', '/^\s|\s$/'), array('', ' ', ''), $text);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/KJPIu)